# On CloudFoundry, HTTP request headers seem to be filtered. Is there a way to receive them?

Tags: http-headers, cloud-foundry

I'm running a NodeJS application on CloudFoundry that is meant to be used in combination with an existing HTTP client which I have no influence on.

This HTTP client sends request headers which my application is dependent on, but iterating through the list of headers has them missing. In contrast, running the NodeJS application on the development machine lists these headers as expected.

The headers in question are application specific, not defined by an RFC document nor do they start with 'X-'. To be precise, the client in question is the in-game-browser of the game "EVE Online". The headers of the client are named with the prefix "eve_", so "eve_trusted" would be a real example.

Below we identified the underscore character ('_') to be a possible problem - Other unknown headers without an underscore do get passed on.

Is there a way to get to the original headers of the request, would this be a feature request for Cloud Foundry or am I lost here as soon as I'm put behind a load-balancer on cloud services in general?

Comment: I have a similar question I'd love answered if you folk have come up with any solutions to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189626/cloudfoundry-nginx-grails-and-the-x-forwarded-header-missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to help understand your issue I deployed a simple node app that would output the headers set by a client so I could use curl to send arbitrary values, the code is as follows;

```
var http = require('http');
var util = require('util');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end(util.inspect(req.headers));
}).listen(3000);
```

I deployed it to http://node-headers.cloudfoundry.com, please feel free to test this yourself, I will leave it live for a while. I then sent a request using the following syntax with curl;

```
curl --header "CustomHeader: Hello" node-headers.cloudfoundry.com
```

This produced the following output;

```
{ host: 'node-headers.cloudfoundry.com',
'x-forwarded-for': '80.175.199.28, 172.30.8.253',
connection: 'close',
'user-agent': 'curl/7.21.4 (universal-apple-darwin11.0) libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8r zlib/1.2.5',
accept: '*/*',
customheader: 'Hello',
'x-cluster-client-ip': '80.175.199.28' }
```

You can see the custom header I sent through with curl. I have also tested this with more than one instance, with the same results.

If there is something I am missing here then please do let me know and I will be more than happy to work through the problem with you.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I tried it with the in-game-browser again and still, no header showed. I then ran your application just as reference, and the header was there. Afterwards I tried it with CURL and found the problem: the header in question has an underscore character ('_') in its name. As soon as you pass "custom_header" for example, this one gets filtered. What magic is happening here?

Comment: ...to finally add an example as well: The headers of the client are named with the prefix "eve_", so "eve_trusted" would be a real example (Although I don't know the exact uppercase/lowercase sequence, should this be of importance as well).

Comment: Hi, I have found the reason for this. In Cloud Foundry all applications are proxied via nginx. It's default behaviour is to not allow underscores in header names. I can verify that reconfiguring nginx to allow this does work as I have changed my own private VCAP instance to do so and it works. I will speak to the engineering team and see if we can change the production environment to allow this.

Comment: Thank you - this would really help in my case and make my application work.

Comment: Hello again! Any news on this configuration change?

Comment: Hi, the change isn't live yet. However, it has been approved for deployment. I will find out later today how long this is likely to take. You can track the progress at http://reviews.cloudfoundry.org/#/c/8533/

Comment: Glad to hear it! Will keep you in the loop as to when it goes live.

Comment: Hello! I know it is a small change compared to possibly more pressing issues, but I'm not sure whether the ticket is now stuck in the review phase or if it is still depending on other factors?

Comment: Hi, sorry about this, I have just sent pinged someone about this and will try and find out where this is.

Comment: Once again, I'd appreciate it if anyone has had any light on the subject if they could kindly review this questions too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18189626/cloudfoundry-nginx-grails-and-the-x-forwarded-header-missing